# basic coding (div with multiple classes)

Tags: html

I am attempting to apply 2 classes to 1 div category and I can't figure out why it won't work

```
<div class="one" class="two"></div>
```

I tried messing with it without the quotations etc, but I am quite new to all this and have no clue what I am doing!

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: Please share your code and what you are trying to do. Without  it, it would be hard to help you out.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] please

Comment: my bad, I typed it in but I apparently formated something wrong it is <div class="one" class="two"></div>.

Comment: i hope this can help https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: It's pretty simple http://jsfiddle.net/o8wv7z3a/ but checkout your selectors, you name them "div category" maybe something wrong there

Comment: great! thank you, I have been messing with this for hours and found this forum on Google